# Are there keyboard shortcuts for adding columns and rows in a draw.io table?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I make a lot of database schemas with [draw.io](https://www.draw.io) but it's annoying to create new rows in the table having to go to the drop down and select the add row icon. Are there any keyboard shortcuts in draw.io to make that task easier?

It would be nice if it was as simple as <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> or something like that.

Comment: I would like this feature also

Answer (score 1):

[Selecting *Help* -> *Keyboard shortcuts...* opens a new tab and displays all of the keyboard shortcuts available in draw.io.](https://support.draw.io/display/DO/Using+the+Help+Menu):

[image: draw.io keyboard shortcuts]

I regret add row/column are not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate row by selecting it and press   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>D</kbd> 
Best solution i've found yet.